# flutter how get directory attributes for writing a plain text file?

Tags: flutter

I need to write text files to external storage. To get permission I use `permission_handler` package. But the problem is that when you get access to `external storage` you can read almost any directory, and write to not every directory `FileSystemException: Cannot open file OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1`

Before i try to write the text file to the directory, is there a way to find out if I am allowed to write there at all? `Directory class` does not have information about directory attributes for reading or writing.

my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the user should confirm by allowing to access to storage
you can check if the permission is granted by the code snippet below

```
  Future<void> checkPermission() async {
 // get permission status
    bool status = await Permission.storage.status;
// checking the permission status is granted or not
    if (status.isDenied) {
// request user permission to access to storage
      status = await Permission.storage.request();
      if (status.isGranted) {
// do writing operation
      }
    } else {
     //permission is already granted 
    }
  }
```

use the path_provider package to get access to the user directory
a link to the package [path_provider_package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

Comment: The question is not about android permissions, the question is about how to check the permission to write a directory.  Even `Permission.storage.status.isGranted` you cannot write to all directories you want